# what is correct ActionListener structure?

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm still a student and I'm not sure what is correct structure for an ActionListener ? is it completely ok to just leave them in the layout constructor ? I don't want to train myself bad habits this early on...

to clarify I'm using google's web toolkit which creates action listeners by default in the constructor however prior to that I used ActionListenerHandler (which is sorta a constructor by itself)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly your question is. Please clarify as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is.. it depends.. 
If it is a one off thing.. you can leave it in the constructor, I assume what you have is anonymous class implementing the ActionListener.

If you want to reuse the ActionListener. You can create a class to implement the ActionListener and simply create instances of that class.

I think some developers don't like creating ActionListeners in the View. Some think it adds logic into a View.

Maybe your View should really expose a method `addSomeActionListener(ActionListener actionListener);`

Comment: so there's no real negatives of having ActionListener in the view ?

Comment: The *best* idea would be to separate them. But for little things like changing text of a label, it is fine.